# Error when executing "rails new APP_NAME"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.1.

When I do a "rails new UtilitiesApp", I get this error:

```
N:\UtilitiesApp>rails new UtilitiesApp
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      .
      .
      .
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:54
:in `stat': No such file or directory - L:/ (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_
fetcher.rb:54:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/source.rb:253:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/source.rb:253:in `fetch_all_remote_specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in `block in remote_specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/source.rb:231:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/source.rb:231:in `remote_specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in `fetch_specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:176:in `block (2 levels) in index'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:175:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:175:in `block in index'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/index.rb:7:in `build'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `index'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:168:in `resolve'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:107:in `specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:102:in `resolve_remotely!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/installer.rb:43:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in `install'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/bin/bundle:13:in `<main>'
Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
```

What is going on here? How do I fix this?

Comment: It looks like Rubygems is trying to save the gems in a location that doesn't exist (the L drive). Looking at my rubygems source code (which could be different than yours), it seems like it probably comes from the line `File.join Gem.user_home, '.gem', 'specs'`. Which implies your home directory is on a nonexistent drive (or rubygems thinks it is). **What is your home directory?** (not sure how to check this on Windows, on Unix it would be `echo $HOME`... if you can't figure it out, you could edit the file that is breaking to print it out just before it breaks)

Comment: @JoshuaCheek Yes, once I set my **HOMEDRIVE** environment variable to a valid directory, it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to set the **HOMEDRIVE** environment variable